# Fix vertical scrolling on true mobile devices (touch devices)

Tags: javascript, android, css, ios, mobile

I have a kanban board, that in responsive mode shows one column at a time. I have added column snapping `scroll-snap-type: x mendatory;` on the parent container, and `scroll-snap-align: center;` on each child. While the horizontal scrolling works well, when trying to scroll vertically (on each column), instead of just scrolling vertically the content jumps all over the place.

URL: https://mymarini.cogency.io/proxy/EDMv?is_embedded=true

Note: this is happening on true mobile devices only, NOT on desktop;

I am pretty sure there must be some sort of CSS solution to this? or possibly a combination of CSS + JS?

PS: The desired intent is to make it work just like in the native trello app.

As requested, here is the CSS code that governs the kanban colums

**Code Snippet**

```css
.app-board-card {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 7px;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.app-board-columns {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) .app-board-columns {
   display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        gap: 1rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overscroll-behavior-x: contain;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.app-board-column {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    width: 330px;
    max-width: 330px;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) .app-board-column {
   width: 260px;
   max-width: 260px;
   scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.app-board-column-inner-scroll {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.app-board-column-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 20px 0 60px 15px;
    min-height: 150px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) .app-board-column-inner {
   padding-right: 15px;
}

.app-board-column.col1 .app-board-card {
   background-color: #fdc6c4;
}
.app-board-column.col2 .app-board-card {
   background-color: #d8edff;
}
.app-board-column.col3 .app-board-card {
   background-color: #eee;
}

/* For demo only */

.app-board-column:after {
  color: gray;
  content: ".app-board-column";
}
.app-board-column {
  border: thin dashed blue;
  min-height: 10rem;
}
.app-board-card {
   min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="app-board-columns">
   <li class="app-board-column col1">
        <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
            <div class="app-board-column-inner">
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
            </div>
        </div>
   </li>
    <li class="app-board-column col2">
        <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
            <div class="app-board-column-inner">
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="app-board-column col3">
        <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
            <div class="app-board-column-inner">
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                <article class="app-board-card"></article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Yogi Please go to the link on your mobile device and try scrolling vertically.

Comment: @Yogi I just added the CSS code that controls the board columns

Comment: @Yogi updated the code

Answer (score 0):

@Art Please test this snippet and check if it works for you.

So basically what I tried to fix was make each card columns scrollable and the entire board should be horizontal scrollable only.

The challenge here would be how we can determine board height to be fitted to the viewport. I set `.app-board-columns` element's height dynamically by using `height: -webkit-fill-available` style and disable vertical scroll with `overflow-y: hidden`.

Hope that make sense.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.app-board-card {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 7px;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.app-board-columns {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;

  min-height: 5rem;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.app-board-column {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 0;
  width: 330px;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 10px 0px 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .app-board-column {
    width: 260px;
    max-width: 260px;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

.app-board-column-inner-scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.app-board-column-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 20px 0 60px 15px;
  min-height: 150px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .app-board-column-inner {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
}

.app-board-column.col1 .app-board-card {
  background-color: #fdc6c4;
}
.app-board-column.col2 .app-board-card {
  background-color: #d8edff;
}
.app-board-column.col3 .app-board-card {
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* For demo only */

.app-board-column:after {
  color: gray;
  content: ".app-board-column";
}
.app-board-column {
  border: thin dashed blue;
  height: 100%;
}
.app-board-card {
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="app-board-columns">
  <li class="app-board-column col1">
    <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
      <div class="app-board-column-inner">
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="app-board-column col2">
    <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
      <div class="app-board-column-inner">
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="app-board-column col3">
    <div class="app-board-column-inner-scroll">
      <div class="app-board-column-inner">
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
        <article class="app-board-card"></article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Yogi, I updated the description.

Comment: thank you for the hard work!! The issue unfortunately was not the scrolling per se, but scrolling vertically on true mobile devices ( not responsive mode on desktop ). If you go to this link on your cell phone, and tried to scroll vertically, you will see the problem. https://mymarini.cogency.io/proxy/EDMv?is_embedded=true

Comment: @Art, I checked the link and I can see the issue in desktop version as well. The entire board is only horizontal scrollable and each columns are vertical scrollable in normal desktop resolution, but somehow if you reduce the width of desktop browser, the entire board gets vertical scrollbar as well, which will generate the issue on mobile version. You will need to get rid of vertical scrolling for the entire board, and each column should only have vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Please test this codepen on your cell phone and let me know if it works.
https://codepen.io/True-Labs/pen/PoVxBbK

Comment: I have loaded the codepen on my iphone using Chrome, and the columns are not vertically scrollable

Comment: also to mention, the issue that I am trying to solve is when you scroll down on a particular column, the column is switched to a different one ... instead of just letting you jusr scroll vertically. It almost feels like you are "swimming" through the board. That happens on a mobile devide, NOT on the desktop!! If that makes sense?